# RNG Application with several random numbers in different TextViews (Android/Java)

Tags: java, android, layout, nullpointerexception, textview

What I'm trying to do:

I'm trying to create an android app, which creates up to 6 different random numbers inside of a grid view. You can adjust the settings with simple number pickers. 
I got 2 nullPointerExceptions, that I can't find to solve:

1. If dice = 1:"java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(int)' on a null object reference"
2. If dice = anything else: "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.GridLayout.addView(android.view.View)' on a null object reference"

Here a part of my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

NumberPicker min = null;
NumberPicker max = null;
NumberPicker dice_amount = null;
int dice = 1;
int[] rng_numbers = new int[6];
TextView[] rng_number_fields = new TextView[6];


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    GridLayout dicelayout = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.dice_layout);

    switch (dice){
        case 1:
            //Numberpicker
            min = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker_min);
            min.setMaxValue(1000);
            min.setMinValue(0);
            min.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);

            max = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker_max);
            max.setMaxValue(1000);
            max.setMinValue(0);
            max.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);

            dice_amount = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker_dice);
            dice_amount.setMaxValue(6);
            dice_amount.setMinValue(1);
            dice_amount.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);
            dice_amount.setValue(dice);

            for(int i=0; i < dice; i++){
                TextView myTextView = new TextView(this);
                myTextView.setText("0");
                myTextView.setWidth(100);
                myTextView.setHeight(100);
                dicelayout.addView(myTextView);
                rng_number_fields[i] = myTextView;
            }
         etc...

}

public void OnButtonClick (View v){

    Button button = (Button) v;

            for( int k: rng_numbers ){
               k = RollDice();
           }
            for(int l=0;l<6; l++){
                    rng_number_fields[l].setText(rng_numbers[l]);
            }
}
```

It would be great if you could tell me my mistake and how to improve this code.

Thanks in advance! :D

Comment: Your first loop count is dependent on the value of dice  but, the loop inside button click has an end var of `5` which will end up trying to access textviews beyond allocated index in array...hence, the null pointer

Comment: That's not the reason for this problem. Still the same error message appears like on 1. I created a TextView array witha  size of 6. This array will be filled depending un the variable "dice" with different TextViews in my grid layout. Afterwards I try to fill those previosly placed TextViews in the OnButtonClick method with random numbers

Comment: When dice value is `1`, your code inside the `case 1` for loop will no run...so, what are the other cases in `switch`?

Comment: 1 till 6, there is the same code inside as in case 1. Yea I understand now, that this wouldnt work like this. The loop would never start because 1<1 would occur and stop it from starting. Correct? I changed the code accordingly. Now only the second error appears. Thank you so far :)

Comment: You are calling `finsViewById()` before calling `setContentView()`. You have two options: 1) Move `GridLayout` initialization inside your switch cases. 2) Move `setContentView()` outside of switch cases before `findViewById()`

Comment: Thanks, this solved the issue. Now in my OnButtonClick method there is the following error: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0 (this line: rng_number_fields[l].setText(rng_numbers[l]);). I tried changing it to "rng_number_fields[l].setText(String.valueOf(rng_numbers[l]));" but a nullpointer error appears: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Comment: Yeah, you have to use `String.valueOf(rng_numbers[i])`...your null pointer for textview is possibly related to my first comment...you are not initialising all the textviews in your array inside switch-cases